# Como parserar JSON da Response no GoLang

Tags: json, api, http, golang

Mais uma vez, eu neste site.

Dessa vez, estou com dificuldade pra parserar a resposta da API que estou me comunicando.A API em questão é esta aqui: https://api.brasil.io/v1/dataset/covid19/caso/data/?is_last=True&state=&city=&is_last=True

```
type Data struct {
    Count    int  `json:"1"`
    Next     bool `json:"null"`
    Previous bool `json:"null"`
    Results  []Cidades
}

type Cidades struct {
    Name      string `json:"city"`
    Confirmed int    `json:"confirmed"`
    Deaths    int    `json:"deaths"`
}

func main() {

   ... código acima disso que faz a requisição com Headers ...

    resp, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    body, readErr := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if readErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(readErr)
    }
    cidade := Cidades{}

    jsonErr := json.Unmarshal(body, &cidade)

    if jsonErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(jsonErr)
    }

    fmt.Println(cidade.Name)

}
```

Toda a autenticação está feita de forma correta (graças a este site lindo).

Eu já tentei parserar apenas o "Results", mas não consigo.

Como posso fazer para, por exemplo, atribuir Deaths a uma variável e Confirmed em outra, por exemplo? Pelo que li, as respostas de `http.Requests` vem em byte, e quando tento parserar pra JSON, ele retorna apenas o Results como string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer o parse do json é necessário primeiro "montar" as estruturas de dados que representam uma resposta válida da nossa API.
Segue um exemplo do json:

```
 var body = `{
        "count": 5616,
        "next": "https://api.brasil.io/v1/dataset/covid19/caso/data",
        "previous": null,
        "results": [
            {
                "city": "blabla",
                "city_ibge_code": "12",
                "confirmed": 54969,
                "confirmed_per_100k_inhabitants": 6145.4269,
                "date": "2021-02-22",
                "death_rate": 0.0176,
                "deaths": 968,
                "estimated_population": 894470,
                "estimated_population_2019": 881935,
                "is_last": true,
                "order_for_place": 343,
                "place_type": "state",
                "state": "AC"
            }]
    }`
```

Após analisar a resposta recebida, devemos fazer um mapeamento adequado da nossa resposta para as nossas estruturas de dados.

Um modelo mais adequado seria:

```
type Cidade struct {
    Name         string      `json:"city"`
    Confirmed    int         `json:"confirmed"`
    Deaths       int         `json:"deaths"`
}
type ApiResultados struct {
    Count    int         `json:"count"`
    Next     string      `json:"next"`
    Previous string      `json:"previous"`
    Results  [] Cidade   `json:"results"`
}
```

Agora que temos uma representação de nossa resposta temos todos os requisitos necessários para transformar a resposta da API em dados que podemos manipular em nossa aplicação.

Para isso utilizamos a função [json.Unmarshall](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/), que vai transformar o nosso array de bytes em nosso objeto `ApiResultados`.

Neste exemplo estou supondo que já fez o request estamos apenas fazendo a leitura dos bytes do nosso objeto `resp`, que possui um resposta de uma chamada que fizemos em uma api, segue o exemplo:

```
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, readErr := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if readErr != nil {
    log.Fatal(readErr)
}
api_resultados := ApiResultados{}

jsonErr := json.Unmarshal(body, &api_resultados)

if jsonErr != nil {
    log.Fatal(jsonErr)
}

fmt.Println(api_resultados.Results[0].Name)
fmt.Println(api_resultados.Results[0].Deaths)
```

Note que depois de fazer a leitura dos bytes do objeto `resp` devemos chamar o método Close() do nosso objeto que possui a resposta afim de evitar vazamento de memória (memory leaks), Este comportamento está [documentado aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238518/what-could-happen-if-i-dont-close-response-body).

## Respondendo à pergunta

> Como posso fazer para, por exemplo, atribuir Deaths a uma variável e
> Confirmed em outra, por exemplo?

Para fazer a atribuição das variáveis basta fazer:

```
confirmados := api_resultados.Results[0].Confirmed
mortes := api_resultados.Results[0].Deaths
fmt.Println(mortes)
fmt.Println(confirmados)
```

Neste exemplo simplificado temos apenas uma cidade dentro do array `"results"` caso possua vários elementos basta iterar com o comando de repetição `for`.

Segue aqui um blog post que detalha melhor várias maneiras de fazer o [encode e decode de informações em Golang](https://blog.golang.org/json)

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou entender o conceito direitinho, novamente.