# iterar sob um slice de struct usando golang (GO)

Tags: array, struct, golang, slice

Estou desenvolvendo uma API que retorna alguns dados json (que estão contidos no body do meu Postman). Consigo listar todos os json com o seguinte código:

```html
data, _ := io.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
    conversion := string(data[:])
    fmt.Println(conversion)
```

agora quero iterar sob os itens de uma struct e retornar o conteúdo deles.
Struct:

```html
type Email_ struct {
    Email         string `json:"email"`
    Timestamp     string `json:"timestamp"`
    Event         string `json:"event"`
    Sg_Event_Id   string `json:"sg_event_id"`
    Sg_Message_Id string `json:"sg_message_id"`
}
```

minha dúvida é: como posso iterar sobre um slice dessa struct?
Eu quero iterar sobre esta struct e retornar os dados que ela contém

Eu tentei esta alternativa, mas retornou um erro:

```html
 data, _ := io.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
    s := []Email_{{Email: string(data)}}
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    typeOfS := v.Type()
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Campo: %s\tValue: %v\n", typeOfS.Field(i).Name, v.Field(i).Interface())
    }
```

erro:

> ```
> reflect: call of reflect.Value.NumField on slice Value
> ```

Comment: uma vez eu respondi uma pergunta parecida. Veja se [ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/496609/103217)

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem um struct de só um tipo, neste caso todos são `string`, então é o mesmo que ter um array (de tamanho fixo) com o mesmo tipo.

Isso é, o struct:

```
type Email_ struct {
    Email         string `json:"email"`
    Timestamp     string `json:"timestamp"`
    Event         string `json:"event"`
    Sg_Event_Id   string `json:"sg_event_id"`
    Sg_Message_Id string `json:"sg_message_id"`
}
```

É exatamente igual à `[5]string`, em memoria.

---

Então, se `unsafe` não for um problema (note que, pelo nome, é sugestivo que isso pode dar muito errado, se não souber o que está fazendo), pode usar o seguinte código:

```
s := Email_{Email: "xxx"}

for _, fieldData := range (*[5]string)(unsafe.Pointer(&s)) {
    fmt.Println(fieldData)
}
```

Por exemplo:

```
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type Email_ struct {
    Email         string `json:"email"`
    Timestamp     string `json:"timestamp"`
    Event         string `json:"event"`
    Sg_Event_Id   string `json:"sg_event_id"`
    Sg_Message_Id string `json:"sg_message_id"`
}

func main() {

    s := []Email_{{Email: "my-email@xxx.com"}}

    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        for _, field := range (*[5]string)(unsafe.Pointer(&s[i])) {
            fmt.Println(field)
        }

    }
    
}
```

---

O seu código, usando reflect, também funciona, mas note que o `s` é um `[]Email_` e não um `Email_`, isso muda tudo, ou seja, para corrigir o seu código basta fazer:

```
for _, s := range s {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    typeOfS := v.Type()
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Campo: %s\tValue: %v\n", typeOfS.Field(i).Name, v.Field(i).Interface())
    }
}
```

No final:

```
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Email_ struct {
    Email         string `json:"email"`
    Timestamp     string `json:"timestamp"`
    Event         string `json:"event"`
    Sg_Event_Id   string `json:"sg_event_id"`
    Sg_Message_Id string `json:"sg_message_id"`
}

func main() {

    s := []Email_{{Email: "my-email@xxx.com"}}

    for _, s := range s {  // <<< Utiliza o seu código do reflect dentro do loop.
        v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
        typeOfS := v.Type()
        for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
            fmt.Printf("Campo: %s\tValue: %v\n", typeOfS.Field(i).Name, v.Field(i).Interface())
        }
    }

}
```